# Can several TeXworks users in a network use one common copy of the Hunspell dictionary stored on a server?

Tags: texworks

Can different TeXworks users, working in a network, have a central place for storing the [Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) dictionary, instead of all having a local copy on their computer? The reason is we need to add new words to the Hunspell dictionary. That would be much easier if we have only one copy of Hunspell in the network.

Comment: Have you considered cloning it from a master git (say) repository?

Comment: What does it mean to "colne from a master repository"?

Comment: It depends exactly on the particular model of distributed version control you need to use, but, for example, you maintain a central set of dictionary versions with git, and the users do a `git pull` to keep their dictionaries up to date. As a complement to this, individual users can update their dictionaries and push back to the master, where the "owner" can approve changes by merging them in. Although this method needs action in the users' machines (which could be done by a daily script, say), it provides you with information when something's out-of-date.

Answer (score 3):

Judging from TeXworks in MiKTeX 2.9 and TeX Live 2012 under Windows I would say it is not possible.

It would require a rewriting of sources, because at the moment the path seems to be hardcoded: one can only choose between dictionaries in different languages, but not the actual underlying files and their path.

<sup>In fact, in the version of TeXworks distributed with TeX Live I cannot even select a single dictionary, because they seem not to be included and they have to be added manually from each user.</sup>